# MYSQL Invalid GIS data provided to function st_geomfromtext for a POINT not a Polygon

Tags: mysql, gis

```
UPDATE
    `points`
SET
    `latitude` = "25.326649141869",
    `longitude` = "49.551773071289",
    `geometry` =(
        ST_GEOMFROMTEXT(
            'POINT((25.326649141869,49.551773071289))'
        )
    ),
    `points`.`updated_at` = "2022-01-17 11 :44 :23"
WHERE
    `id` = "7017ef8a4f2df74705338316"
```

In the query above I am trying to update this record but I received MYSQL error Invalid GIS data provided to function st_geomfromtext

**Note:** however the same values for the st_geomfromtext fun works fine when inserting the record before.

Comment: Ran into this problem. It seems the format is POINT(longitude,latitude)

Answer (score 0):

See WKT description for the expected format:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Well-known_text_representation_of_geometry

In particular, for Points, you only need one set of parenthesis. The longitude and latitude are separated by space, not comma.